# Open and save entire workbook and not just a sheet pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

On Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.3.4

So I'm trying to use Pandas to write to a workbook while saving the entire workbook as a whole and not sheet by sheet.

For example, `test.xlsx` has 3 sheets named `Sheet1`,`Sheet2`, and `Sheet3`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Currently, I'm getting an error of `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`.

I'm trying to open the workbook, write some data to a sheet and save the workbook as a whole.

Comment: My recommendation: avoid using pandas for this. But your current error is that `df` is a `dict` of dataframes, as explained in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: @BigBen would openpyxl be more of the move to do something like this?

Comment: Yes openpyxl or xlsxwriter, among others.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using pandas for this, you need:

```
for name,sheet in df.items():
    sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name )
```